# XLConnect crashing R when java.params modified

Tags: java, r, xlconnect

Loading the `XLConnect` package after modifying the `java.parameters` options (possibly incorrectly) crashes R on my local machine.  On a remote machine, attempting to load the package throws an error. (Both R 3.0.2)

The linux machine has ample RAM (100+ GB) and R handles the error gracefully
The local machine has 8GB RAM and R abruptly crashes when loading the XLConnect package
This happens in Terminal with R --vanilla and in the RGUI

The error thrown reads:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified

Any thoughts or suggestions?  I realize that there is a java issue here, but why the abrupt exit by R?

#### Reproducible Example:

```
R --vanilla

## Attempt to set params
options(java.parameters = "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Xrs")

library(rJava)      # Loads 
library(XLConnect)  # Crashes


## Also attempted these other options
options(java.parameters = "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m")
options(java.parameters = "-Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xrs")
options(java.parameters = "-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Xrs")
```

### INFO

```
LINUX BOX: 
OS:  CentOS 6.4
R: 3.0.2
XLConnect: 0.2-7
rJava: 0.9-6
Java: 7 (build 1.7.0_45-b18)

LOCAL MACHINE: 
OS:  Mac OSX 10.9.1
R: 3.0.2
XLConnect: 0.2-7
rJava: 0.9-6
Java: 7 (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
```

Comment: Did you try without the -Xrs option?

Comment: Hi Martin, yes I did. In the middle of my OP, I wrote a few additional options parameters I have tried